# HeapCreate, HeapAlloc in Linux, private allocator for Linux

Tags: c++, windows, linux, memory, allocation

In Windows, for very demanding  applications, a programmer may use HeapCreate, HeapAlloc in order to better manage and control the allocation of memory- speed it up (aka private allocators). What is the equivalent in Linux c++ programming?

Comment: Can you provide a Comparison of Windows Source code using HeapCreate(). HeapAlloc(). Heapfree().
and source code using mmap(). functions to do the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use your own private allocator, then use `mmap()` to map an amount of memory into your process, then you can use that memory as you like. Open a file descriptor to `/dev/zero`, and then use that as the 'fildes' parameter to `mmap()`. See `man mmap` for full details of the parameters to pass. In this respect `mmap()` plays the same role as `HeapCreate()`.

Comment: You don't need to open `/dev/zero` - you can just use the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag and pass -1 as the `fd` argument.

Comment: True, and it's often faster if you do, though `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is less portable (e.g. it's not included in SUSv2). But you're right, it would almost certainly do in this situation :-)

Comment: OP asked for a heap, not just a block of memory. Most real-life malloc implementations are very complicated.

Comment: @Soonts: No, they asked how they could better manage/control the allocation of memory, and speed it up, on Linux in C++, using private allocators. One option is using a general-purpose malloc() implementation, sure, but the one in glibc is already highly optimised; if you want to do better than that you typically have to take advantage of some aspect of your memory use patterns (eg if all your allocations are the same size, or you always free all memory at once, you can simplify things a lot). This answer describes how you reserve memory from the OS so that you can manage it yourself.