# why is this c++ struct 96 bytes of memory?

Tags: c++, memory, struct

i cant see why this struct takes up 96 bytes of ram.

```
struct cell
{
    bool filled;
    bool isParent;
    short int mat;
    bool cx,cy,cz;
    vect norm;
    struct cell* child[8];
    struct cell* parent;
    cell(float pxx=0, float pyy=0, float pzz=0, float ss=0, cell *par=NULL, bool cxx=0, bool cyy=0, bool czz=0);

    void open_read(string);
};
```

I know about word allignment, but this should atleast not be more than 64 bytes i think...
there will be many millions of instances of this struct so how could i get the memory footprint to a minimum?
I am using linux and vect is a vector(3 floats)

Comment: What is `vect`?

Comment: How did you measure it?

Comment: If this isn't a 32 bit system pointers alone would take 8 bytes each

Comment: `struct cell* child[8];` would be 64 bytes on a 64-bit machine on its own. 8 bytes more for "parent", makes 72, so how you come up with anything less, I'm not sure. plus 12 bytes for your "vect", makes 84. The bytes before that is a total of 7, but add one for alignment there, and a few bytes to align to 8 bytes for child array.

Comment: oh, dident think of that everywere i read pointers was only 4... would this change by compiling it as a 32bit binary and run it with multi lib support?

Comment: you should order your members according to their individual size as well, this will allow for less padding to be added upon compilation.

Comment: because i need to be able to keep as many cell's in memory as possible. at least a few of millions, but the more the better.

Comment: If you use 32 bit pointers, you will only be able to reference 4 GB of memory.. If you need lots of memory, this might not be enough

Comment: You can use bitfield to pack all your bools into a single short. A "few million" needs ~20 bits - 24 if you want a billion - so you could consider referencing cells by index and then devoting the upper bits of the child references to your boolean fields, and maybe even your short. "isParent" is strictly unnecessary, just check whether the first child is valid.

Comment: I agree with the downvote on this question on the basis that if you could check the size of the structure, you could have then tested the size of all the elements.  However, I'm upvoting to negate that because this is a legitimate question about how one might optimize the structure for memory size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much you can do about your pointers.

However, you can condense all your booleans down to a single byte by using either single-bit enumerators or bitfields.  Depending on the maximum value of `mat`, you may be able to condense the flags AND that value into two bytes.  It's not a big saving.

If you expect your tree to be extremely dense, you may get significant gains by allocating your children as a pool.  That is, you have a single `struct cell* child` pointer which references a block of memory that is an array of all eight children.  Then you save the space of 7 pointers per record with the understanding that every non-leaf node will allocate more memory than it requires.  And you probably need a flag to indicate the node is empty.

Alternatively, you could chain your children as a list if you want to sacrifice the random-access of an array.  Then you just need a single `child` pointer and a single `sibling` pointer.  A saving of 6 pointers per node and no wastage from pooling.  It gets a bit finnicky though.

Comment: thanks, will look into that. there will never be some empty child and some not. all 8 childs will either be empty or not(indicated by isParent).

Comment: In that case you should definitely get rid of the pointer array.  Allocate your children as `child = malloc(8 * sizeof(struct cell))` (if the cell has children).  Combine that with the bit packing I suggested, and your struct reduces to a `char`, a `short`, 3 `floats` and 2 pointers.  You don't need `isParent` because you know that from whether `child` is `NULL`.  I'm starting to wonder about your other flags now.  Maybe they're not necessary either.

Comment: Oh I probably should have said to use `new[]` instead of `malloc`, since you tagged this as C++ =)  It just looks very C-ish.  My bad.

Comment: ok, that will help quite a bit. as for the other flags i will need to try to see how my program can be changed. (btw i use this for a sparce voxel octree so i need to be able to do raycast into it)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obviously 8 byte pointers on 64 bit systems

If you're really trying to minimize memory footprint, and you're willing to dance in order to achieve it, we can try to reduce the pointer size

Moving to 32 bit pointers isn't recommended because then you only have access to 4 GB of ram, which may not be enough if you're using up lots and lots of memory

I can suggest this somewhat crazy approach:

For your struct, use a custom allocator instead of the regular heap. A custom allocator basically means that for instances of this specific struct, you are using a separate heap that you manage yourself. On Windows OS this is very easy to do with HeapCreate(), on Linux, use mmap as referenced by this question: [HeapCreate, HeapAlloc in Linux, private allocator for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880639/heapcreate-heapalloc-in-linux-private-allocator-for-linux)

Since we have a separate heap for this struct type, this heap will only allocate and deallocate instances of this struct. This by itself is one big optimization since having all allocations of exactly the same size eliminates heap fragmentation.

Now, for the trick. Since every instance is inside this separate heap, we can give it an index. Simply take its allocated pointer, subtract the heap start pointer and divide by the struct size. The first struct in the heap will get the index 0, the second is index 1 and so forth. What we will do, is save the index of the struct instead of the pointer to the struct. These indexes are much more space-efficient and can easily be transformed back to pointers.

This approach will of course only minimize pointers to your cell struct.. Not general pointers in the general-purpose heap. If you feel that dividing by the struct size is dangerous (you assume all structs are continuous in the heap when you do that), just skip this step, it only saves a couple of bits. Simply substructing the heap start is probably enough to save you lots of space.

A bit overkill, but fun nevertheless :)

Comment: :) think i will start by doing some more general optimizations first, but might look into it if i need to reduce it even more. would this affect the speed of accessing the childs/parent?

Comment: The effect would be very small, you only add a couple of instructions when you need to convert index to pointer. Should be negligible

Answer (score 0):

Talkol's suggestion of using a custom allocator is a good one.  If structures will be accessed in random order and you're interested in achieving optimal performance, it may be good to work things so your structure is exactly bytes, and is aligned on a 64-byte boundary.  Data is fetched into cache from main memory in 64-byte chunks called "lines"; the CPU can execute dozens or hundreds of instructions in the time required to fetch a chunk from main memory into cache.  If structures will be accessed in random order, having them aligned will mean that reading each structure will require loading only one cache line rather than two.

Note that if data will sometimes be accessed sequentially, a smaller structure may improve efficiency, since even if accessing one requires fetching two cache lines, accessing the next would require fetching at most one; if a structure takes 48 bytes, each group of four structures accessed would require only three cache-line fetches, but random accesses would require on average 1.5 cache-line fetches.

Comment: will try paddy's answer first and use this if i need to make it more efficent.